# What is the verb for amenable?

Tags: suffixes, etymology

amenable has a suffix -able. Does it mean that the verb for amenable is amend? Thanks.

Comment: Not all words ending in *-able* have corresponding English verbs. Some of them come from Latin.

Comment: Interesting question.  But no, *amenable* doesn't mean "capable of being amended".  Merriam-Webster says ["Amenable is a legacy of Anglo-French and derives ultimately from Latin minari, meaning "to threaten." Since 1596, English speakers have been using it in courtrooms and writings of law with the meaning "answerable," as in "citizens amenable to the law." It later developed the meanings "suited" and "responsive".  It also came to be used of people with a general disposition to be agreeable or complaisant."](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/amenable)

Comment: I think I'm going to have to vote to close this question, because it's something that can be answered simply by referring to the definition.

Comment: Am I missing something here? Where does OP get that /d/ from? Just as the base verb for ***dependable*** is ***defend***, if there *were* a base verb for ***amenable*** it would be ***amen***. Which has been used as a verb ([*The congregation “amened” him at every opportunity during his sermon*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22congregation+amened%22), for example), so arguably a preacher who wants to deliver memorable "soundbytes" might be interested in making sure his sermon contains lots of "amenable" elements.

Answer (score 1):

No, "to amend" means to "add to" or "attach to the end of", like a document or a statement.  *Amenable* itself has no verb form -- it's a simple adjective like "hot" or "blue".

There are verbs that mean "to *make* or *become* amenable":

**Transitive** (make someone amenable to)

*appease, satisfy, befriend, etc.*

**Intransitive** (become amenable to)

*acquiesce, agree, concede, accede, consent, etc*.